# Is there a formula for calculating the integral of a polynomial times a trig function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm wondering if there is a formula for calculating the integral of a polynomial times a single trig function. For example, integrating $$\int_a^b (t^2 - t) \cos (t) dt$$

I realize that to integrate, I just need to split it up into one integral for each polynomial term and then integrate by parts multiple times, so I am wondering if there is a closed formula (I suspect there is)

Comment: You don't need to split it up, just set $u$ to be the entire polynomial. It still works because it's still a product.

Comment: @Dylan yeah I realize that now; but we still need to integrate by parts multiple times perhaps.

Comment: Generally the number of times you IBP is equal to the degree of the polynomial

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try using integration by parts. Namely with u = t^2 - t. Remember, you may have to do integration by parts multiple times.

Comment: I mean that doesn't get rid of the problem of having to integrate by parts multiple times (which is what I was trying to avoid by "Cheating" and getting a nice formula)

Comment: [try this website.](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx) The part you're concerned with is example 9.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

$$ u = t^2 - t $$
$$ dv = \cos t \, dt $$

The number of times you integrate by parts should not be more than the power of the highest0degree term

Comment: Yea I realize. The point of my post is that I wanted a formula so I could be lazy and not have to integrate by parts $n$ times.  I guess I'll just bite the bullet and do it.